# Prevent Last 'N' password reuse - MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, password-encryption, change-password

I have a login form that I created in MVC 3 which has a 'change password' view.
At the moment there are no restrictions with respect to reusing previous passwords. 
I understand that I'd need to create a custom password manager as ASP.net  has nothing out the box for this. 
I have a 'previousPassswords' table created.

currently , my 'changePassword' controller looks like this:

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather
                // than return false in certain failure scenarios.
                bool changePasswordSucceeded;
                try
                {
                    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true /* userIsOnline */);
                    changePasswordSucceeded = currentUser.ChangePassword(model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    changePasswordSucceeded = false;
                }

                if (changePasswordSucceeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ChangePasswordSuccess");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
```

I'd like to compare new  passwords (preferrably encrypted) with the last 'n' passwords in the previousPasswords table an act accordingly.

Is this the recommended approach  or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't check on previous passwords (compare: https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-63b.pdf).

First, it increases the Chance that users go for easier and therefore more insecure Passwords:
'I can't use *myPassword* as Password any longer? well the make it *password* then'. Or worse: 'I can't use my individual Password? Well, I'm gonna use the email password then'

Secondly, if your user data get stolen/hacked the effect will be even worse: you won't loose one Password per user but multiple.

For Password policies, check Paragraph 5.1

Comment: Currently, there are rules with regards to password complexity so I don't see how new passwords can be simpler if a user adheres to the rules set in place. I'd just like to be able to restrict users from  using old passwords. and the comparison is normally done against the encrypted/hashed passwords not clear text.

Comment: First of all, I hope that all your Passwords are stored hashed and salted.

Comment: New Passwords can be simpler because a user is too lazy to think of a new one he has to memorize. That's the same reason, why periodical password change shall not be enforced. Also, rules towards password complexity should be kept to the absolute bare Minimum (check the link in my answer.)

Comment: There are reasons why periodical password change is usefull. 
For more details take a look at: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4704/how-does-changing-your-password-every-90-days-increase-security